# i have single API to test and i want achieve 30K TPS with this API. Can any body explain me fully how to test this with Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have single API to test and I want achieve 30K TPS with this API. Can any body explain me fully how to test this with Jmeter ?
It may be with 20 , 40 or 60 Users but I want to acheive this using Jmeter UI mode?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad.

Anyway, the simple and straight answer is that you may not be able to achieve this in the UI mode and you may require multiple slaves. If your API has an SLA of 1 second, a single thread executing with 1 second pacing will result in 3600 transactions in an hour (1 TPS). So, you will require 30,000 threads in JMeter to achieve 30,000 TPS.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter GUI isn't for Load Testing rather the test plan debugging purpose only. GUI is very resource intensive and consumes a lot of memory. It is better and highly suggested to perform load testing in [Non-GUI](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) mode.

When you run your JMeter in GUI mode you will see this:

[image]

As 30K TPS is too high and to test this you have to give enough number of threads. To calculate how many threads you need for this test, you also need to know the API's max response time.

Here is the formula for thread number calculations:

> TPS* max response time in second

For example, if you have response time `1 second`, then to generate `30K TPS` you need `30K threads`. If API's response time is `500ms`, then you need at least `15K threads`.

To generate this high load, you also need to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html), cause you won't be able to generate such a high load from a single machine. To determine how many threads you can generate from a single machine, you also need to test this yourself. Try to gradually increase the thread number and monitor the machine's health.  If it consumes `70-80%` of your machine's health (CPU, Memory, Disk), then stop the test and mark the number of threads. Now you can assume how many machines you need to test this scenario.

Finally, I suggest you to double check your test requirements because 30K TPS (`108000000` requests per hour) is too high!

See [Apache JMeter's Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) for more.